# Cast not casting

Tags: typescript, angular

I made a simple Http call:

```
http.get('/test/data/user.json').
    map(res => <User> res.json()).
    subscribe(user => {
        console.log(typeof user);
        console.log(user);
        console.log(user.getName());
});
```

with the following data in `user.json`:

```
{
    "name":"Robert"
}
```

and the following `User` class:

```
export class User{
    name:string;
    lastName:string;
    getName():string{
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Problem is the result I get in console:

```
console.log(typeof user);
```

> object

```
console.log(user);
```

> Object {name: "Robert"}

```
console.log(user.getName());
```

> Uncaught TypeError: user.getName is not a function

#### Problem

Problem here is that my object is an `object`, not a `User`, so it does not have all properties, and it has no methods.

Also tried with Promise-based call and `user.json() as User` instead of `<User> res.json()`

EDIT: not similar to casting to an interface since interface doesn't have its own behaviour.

Comment: Typescript is only a compile time type checker, it doesn't work at run time...

Comment: I know that but object should have lastName property.

Comment: what you are requiring is something like `subscribe(userObj => let user = new User(userObj))` where you actually transform the object into the User class.

Comment: It will only have the lastName property if that came down the wire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 cast a json result to an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516332/angular2-cast-a-json-result-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `getName` method, you need to instantiate an new `User` object when mapping the response body:

```
http.get('/test/data/user.json').
  map(res => {
    let body = res.json();
    return new User(body.name, body.lastName);
  })
  subscribe(user => {
    console.log(typeof user);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(user.getName());
  });
```

The `User` class would be adapted like below:

```
export class User{
  constructor(private name:string, private lastName:string) {}

  getName():string{
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Casting an object won't add method to an existing object. The `json` method of the response will simply parse the response body using `JSON.parse` and return a raw object.

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7lKHvArpayrMAzm5Xgk1?p=preview.