# Angular 2 call model method in component template

Tags: angular

How can I call a method on my model from my component template? At present I get that the method `is not a function`

At present my model is something like this:

```
export class Profile {
    ProfileID: number;
    TrialEnd: Date;
    Purchased: boolean;

    GetStatus() {
        if (this.Purchased) {
            return "Purchased";
        }
        else if (Date.now() < this.TrialEnd.getTime()) {
            return "Trial";
        }
        else {
            return "Expired"
        }
    }
}
```

and I have an array of these in my profiles page displayed like this.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let prof of profiles">
        <td>{{prof.ProfileID}}</td>
        <td>{{prof.TrialEnd}}</td>
        <td>{{prof.Purchased}}</td>
        <td>{{prof.GetStatus()}}</td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Where `profiles: Profile[]`

However this errors because prof.GetStatus isn't accessible.

Comment: Your `prof` is most probably not an instance of Profile. Have you tried calling the function from your component? My guess is that you got a JSON response from your backend, and "casted" it to a Profile[], but the objects in the JSON are raw JS objects, without any method.

Comment: Yes. That just proves that you have an object with those three fields. Not that it's an instance of Profile. What happens when you cann that method from the component? How did you create this array of profiles?

Comment: Yeah sorry I realised that just after I commented. You're right. What would be the recommended way for adding a helper method like that to a model so? Should I calculate it server side and pass it back, or can I do it clientside in the model somehow, or should I do it clientside and pass it to the model on receiving the data?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: `TypeError: prof.GetStatus is not a function` - @JBNizet seems to have solved the cause. But I'm still not sure what's the best way to fix it.

Comment: There are various techniques: use a utility function from outside the model, create an instance of Profile from the received JSON object by copying fields (probebly the best one), binding methods to the JSON objects when they're received. I still wonder why JavaScript/TypeScript don't have a proper JSON unmarshaller, that can parse JSON to actual class instances. Doing everything at server-side seems like the worst idea to me. For a functional status, it might be acceptable, but there are UI-related methods that the server-side shouldn't deal with.

Comment: Following what @JBNizet explained I think that this question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181826/cast-not-casting/36182096#36182096 ;-)

Comment: Thanks a million for the help! Sorted now :)